# How can I configure GitHub Actions to build my Azure Static Web App with a dependency on a private repository?

Tags: azure, github, yarnpkg, github-actions, azure-static-web-app

I've built an Azure Static Web App with one API function which has one dependency. This dependency sits in a private repository on GitHub. On my local dev machine I'm able to build the Functions app by downloading the dependency using SSH authentication. When trying to deploy to Azure using GitHub Actions I get the error `Host key verification failed`.

My GitHub Actions workflow is similar to the default workflow generated by Azure Static Web App, with the addition of using [webfactory/ssh-agent](https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent) for facilitating the SSH authentication on GitHub to retrieve the private repository *Y* and a run step with `git clone` for testing purposes:

```yaml
# ... Same as on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/github-actions-workflow

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true
          persist-credentials: false
      - uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.1
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE }}
      - run: |
          git clone ssh://git@github.com/X/Y.git Z
          ls -la Z
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TOKEN }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/"
          api_location: "api"
          output_location: "build"

# ... Same as on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/github-actions-workflow
```

In my private repository *Y* I've added the public key associated to private key `secrets.SSH_PRIVATE` as a deploy key.

After running the workflow it shows the `git clone` command is ran correctly as the `ls -la` command results in displaying the directories and files in my private repository. However, the build process of my API (`yarn install --prefer-offline --production`) results in the error `Host key verification failed` when yarn is fetching the packages. As a result, GitHub Actions cannot download the dependency in my private repository, and cannot build the API. This ends with a failed workflow.

Comment: Is the build process (with the yarn command) executed on another step? If it is, check the directory before executing the command to see if you're still in the expected directory. I recently perform something similar with git and had to enter the directory to execute operations in each step.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! No, the build process is included in Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview, so in the same step as where I initiate the ssh-agent.

Comment: I found in another topic that it may be because using the `git@github.com:...` syntax ends up using SSH to clone, and that inside the container, your private key might not be available. In that case, you might want to use RUN `git clone https://github.com/x/y.git` instead (source (even if different): https://github.com/docker-library/golang/issues/148).

Comment: Thanks, I think this pushed me in the right direction. As being new to GitHub Actions I didn't realise the action `Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview` spins up a Docker container. This container indeed has no idea about `webfactory/ssh-agent` which runs on the host VM. Now to figure out how to easily "inject" the host key and my private SSH key in the container...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing `Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview` I noticed it uses [Oryx](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx) to start a Docker container for the build process of the Azure Static Web App. This container is unaware of the ssh-agent that was initialized using `webfactory/ssh-agent` on the host VM. As a result the `yarn install` triggered in `Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview` couldn't download the dependency that was in my private repository and failed the installation.

To circumvent this I've refactored my private dependency to use it as a [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) instead, because submodules can be loaded prior to the build process using [`actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout). This was achieved by adding only two extra lines to the workflow file that is generated by [Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/github-actions-workflow). I've highlighted these two lines with a trailing `# ADDED` in the following snippet of my workflow file:

```yaml
jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ssh-known-hosts: "github.com" # ADDED
          ssh-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE }} # ADDED
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview
...
```